# Max(Value) of columns based on other columns - SQL

Tags: sql-server, group-by, max

I have seen some similar questions I have not been able use it tocomplete my query:

I have a lot of hourly forecast data, and new forecast is coming in each hour and they all forecast from now to a couple of days ahead. My goal is to create a query(to use in a view) that gives me the forecasted data from the latest forecast for everyday(date and hour).

FDate = Forecasted Date

FHour = Forecasted Hour

RDate = The date forecast is made

RHour = The hour forecast is made

My table:

```
 FDate       FHour   Value   RDate       RHour
 2018-09-02  10      99      2018-09-02  9
 2018-09-02  10      82      2018-09-02  8
 2018-09-02  10      86      2018-09-01  20
```

In this example, I only want the first line, because that is the newest forecast.

I have come up with a query that is giving me the forecasted data from the latest date the forecast is made but not the latest hour.

```
SELECT t.FDate, t.FHour, t.Value, t.RDate, t.RHour 
FROM MyTable t 
INNER JOIN (
SELECT FDate, MAX(RDate) As MaxDate
FROM Mytable 
GROUP BY FDate) tm t.FDate = tm.FDate AND t.RDate = tm.MaxDate
```

I have tried to include MAX(RHour) in the query but it gives me only earlier dates than today and the latest date in the forecast, not the once in between. Example: from yesterday and earlier and then 2018-09-10, which is the last day in the forecast, it wouldn't give me 2018-09-06 and so on.

The result of my query:

```
FDate       FHour   Value   RDate       RHour
2018-09-02  10      99      2018-09-02  9
2018-09-02  10      82      2018-09-02  8
```

Again my goal is to only return the first line.

Comment: How did you determine that the first line is the newest? Also can you include the result of your query.

Comment: The first line is the newest because it is the latest RDate and RHour for the given FDate and FHour ... I edited the result of my query.

Comment: Do you want the latest forecast data or the latest forecast data for every day?

Comment: Yes, I may not have explained it correctly, but I need to create a view with all the lasted forecast data for every day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this is with row_number function, because it will let you order by whatever you need to.

As an example, if you want the last row for a given FDate you would do something like:

```
;with t as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by FDate, fHour 
                                 order by RDate desc, RHour desc) r
    from myTable
)
select * from t where r=1
```

You can see that this can be tailored to partition by whatever you want (in this example I'm guessing the FDate and FHour), and order by whatever you want. All up to you.

Comment: Thanks! - is it possible to makes it apply only to data from yesterday and older and get all data for today and not only the latest forecast?

Comment: Not sure I understand the restriction but you can add any sort of where clause you like either inside the CTE, in the final select, or if you need to order by some strange condition then include `order by case when <condition> then 0 else 1 end` to provide whatever overriding order you want. Its completely flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Get the latest record by the date and hour, use `ORDER BY` on both columns and sort both descending (`DESC`).

Get only the first row, use `TOP(1)`.

```
SELECT TOP(1) *
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY RDate DESC, RHour DESC
```